# Bash: let statement vs assignment

Tags: linux, bash, unix

What is the difference between assigning to a variable like `var=foo` and using let like `let var=foo`? Or cases like `var=${var}bar` and `let var+=bar`? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`let` does exactly what `(( ))` do, it is for arithmetic expressions. There is [almost no difference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let#examples) between `let` and `(( ))`.

Your examples are invalid. `var=${var}bar` is going to add word `bar` to the `var` variable (which is a string operation), `let var+=bar` is not going to work, because it is not an arithmetic expression:

```
$ var='5'; let var+=bar; echo "$var"
5
```

Actually, it IS an arithmetic expression, if only variable `bar` was set, otherwise `bar` is treated as zero.

```
$ var='5'; bar=2; let var+=bar; echo "$var"
7
```

Comment: One difference is that `let` allows some degree of indirection: `a=b; b=3; let $a+=1; echo $b;`. The argument to `let` undergoes parameter expansion before being evaluated (which I don't think I saw mentioned in the link you posted).

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I thought that after `a=b; b=3`, the two commands `(( a+=1 ))` and `(( $a+=1 ))` would be equivalent, but they aren't. The first seems to replace `a` with the value of `b`, then increments, leaving the value of `b` untouched. The second increments `b` while leaving `a` set to the string `b`.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2219) explains why `((...))` should be used in favor of `let`